# Kibana Container Error msg pulling image failed error pull access denied for fxlabs/kibana7 repository does not exist

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, docker-compose, kibana

Below are the file of kibana and Kibana container is not running is excited after 1mint after its deploy.

1. This is my docker-stack.yaml file

/home/mohd/Music/Exception-Email-Notification/docker-elk/docker-stack.yml

```
version: '3.3'

#networks:
# host:
# driver: overlay
# attachable: true

volumes:
elasticsearch:
logstash:
kibana:

services:

nginx:
image: nginx:latest
volumes:
- ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

elasticsearch:
image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.0.1
ports:
# - "9200:9200"
- "9300:9300"
configs:
- source: elastic_config
target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
environment:
# ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
ELASTIC_USERNAME: "elastic"
ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
# ELASTIC_USERNAME: "kibana"
# ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
# http.cors.enabled: "true"
# http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
# xpack.security.enabled: "true"
# networks:
# - host
volumes:
- elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
deploy:
mode: replicated
replicas: 1

logstash:
image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.0.1
ports:
# - "5000:5000"
- "5044:5044"
- "9600:9600"
configs:
- source: logstash_config
target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:rw
- source: logstash_pipeline
target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
volumes:
- logstash:/usr/share/logstash/data
# - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:rw
# - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro

environment:
LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
# xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: "elasticsearch:9200"
# xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
# xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: "xxxxxx"
# networks:
# - host
deploy:
mode: replicated
replicas: 1

kibana:
image: fxlabs/kibana7:latest
# ports:
# - "5601:5601"
volumes:
- kibana:/usr/share/kibana/data
configs:
- source: kibana_config
target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
# environment:
# ELASTIC_USERNAME: "elastic"
# ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
# - "elasticsearch.username: elastic"
# - "elasticsearch.password: xxxx"
# http.cors.enabled: "true"
# http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
# xpack.security.enabled: "true"
# networks:
# - host
deploy:
mode: replicated
replicas: 1
caddy:
image: openfaas/caddy
# image: fxlabs/caddy
# image: stefanprodan/caddy
# image: abiosoft/caddy
ports:
- "5601:5601"
- "9200:9200"
# - "5044:5044"
- "3030:3030"
# - "8080:8080"
# networks:
# - net
# environment:
# - ADMIN_USER= admin
# - ADMIN_PASSWORD= xxxxxx
# configs:
# - source: caddy_config
# target: /etc/caddy/Caddyfile
volumes:
- /home/docker-elk/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
# - /home/ubuntu/docker-elk/caddy/cert.crt:/etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.crt
# - /home/ubuntu/docker-elk/caddy/cert.key:/etc/pki/tls/private/cert.key
deploy:
mode: replicated
replicas: 1
placement:
constraints:
- node.role == manager
resources:
limits:
memory: 128M
reservations:
memory: 64M

configs:

elastic_config:
file: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
logstash_config:
file: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
logstash_pipeline:
file: ./logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
kibana_config:
file: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml

#networks:
# elk:
# driver: overlay
```

2. This is my kibana.yaml file

/home/mohd/Music/Exception-Email-Notification/docker-elk/kibana/config/kibana.yml

```
---
## Default Kibana configuration from kibana-docker.
## from https://github.com/elastic/kibana-docker/blob/master/build/kibana/config/kibana.yml
#
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
#elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
#elasticsearch.hosts: http://elasticsearch:9200
elasticsearch.hosts: http://nginx
#elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.username: "test"
elasticsearch.password: "xxxx"
#elastalert-kibana-plugin.serverHost: 123.0.0.1
#elastalert-kibana-plugin.serverPort: 9000
#timeout= 90000ms
#elasticsearch.timeout: "90000ms"
#readonly:
# cluster:
# - cluster:monitor/nodes/info
# - cluster:monitor/health
# indices:
# '*':
# privileges: indices:test/mappings/fields/get, indices:test/validate/query, indices:data/read/search, indices:data/read/msearch, indices:data/read/field_stats, indices:test/get
# '.kibana':
# privileges: indices:test/exists, indices:test/mappings/fields/get, indices:test/refresh, indices:test/validate/query, indices:data/read/get, indices:data/read/mget, indices:data/read/search

#elastalert.enabled:
elastalert-kibana-plugin.serverHost: elastalert
elastalert-kibana-plugin.serverPort: 3030

#sentinl:
# settings:
# email:
# active: true
# user: rashid7@gmail.com
# password: xxxxxx
# host: smtp.gmail.com
# port: 465
# ssl: true
# report:
# active: true
#
# slack:
# active: true
# token: xoxp-483014078565-482209664337-590134404704-38b035ea03ee31e25941db5e6f1957e3
#
```

1. ERROR
   Another error im getting when i type this command in terminal
   docker-elk$ tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep kibana

```
May 18 16:55:40 master-node dockerd[24124]: time="2021-05-18T16:55:40.339808478+05:30" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/fxlabs/kibana7/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Afxlabs%2Fkibana7%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
May 18 16:57:56 master-node dockerd[24124]: time="2021-05-18T16:57:56.669087844+05:30" level=error msg="pulling image failed" error="pull access denied for fxlabs/kibana7, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=kwpyr5ixo3xx6psp782zxtgre service.id=10h7ton3yj4y4xfqbcxkc2x7c task.id=azbqxjx4w4u5oy2gwwa11kmh5
```

2. ERROR
   docker-elk$ docker container logs fe5fe4f19954 (kibana container logs)

```
elastalert-kibana-plugin, kibana, stateSessionStorageRedirect, status_page and timelion. This may take a few minutes"}
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-05-19T05:48:52Z","tags":["info","optimize"],"pid":1,"message":"Optimization of bundles for elastalert-kibana-plugin, :["status","plugin:elasticsearch@undefined","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
<title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>\\r\\n<body>\\r\\n<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>\\r\\n<hr><center>nginx/1.19.10</center>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n\"}\n    at respond (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:308:15)\n    at checkRespForFailure (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:267:7)\n    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:166:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4935:19)\n
```

1. Pulling image failed" error="pull access denied for fxlabs/kibana7, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied" :-  Even image already exit in docker hub but still error is showing
2. 405 Not Allowed,  message: 'Method Not Allowed :- This error i dont know where it coming and how to solve it

Please tell me where im wrong from 4 days im not able to solve it everything i have done to solve it but still i didnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an image there called fxlabs/kibana7 it's the second last image definition in your docker-stack.yaml file

There is not a registry url like the other images in front of it, that means it's searching dockerhub.io for the image. Also evident from the error you posted

```
pull access denied for fxlabs/kibana7, repository does not exist
```

From a quick search there does not seem to be an image called that there

Your solution if it does exist is to put a registry where it exists in front of the image
or
If it is on docker hub it is a private image and you need to run `docker login` on the machine before you run this

Comment: I solve above issue by comment the define.conf file in that 
        add_header Allow "GET, POST, HEAD" always;
        if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD)$ ) {
 return 405; 
All line above i have comment it and after i restart the container of kibana is work fine